# Documenting Unit tests in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go, code-documentation

Whoever writes unit tests in Go, how are you documenting them?

Is there some kind of 'docstring' (like in Python) convention?
If so, how do you maintain this documentation afterwards?
Is it possible to generate Docs based on the description from Unit tests with some automatic tool?
I am asking because as a QA person in my team i wish to document those tests and maintain them as a part of an ongoing dev cycle.

Answer (score 2):

> Whoever writes unit tests in GoLang, how are you documenting them?

Not in any systematic way (if at all).

> Is there some kind of 'docstring' (like in Python) convention?

No. (For executable *examples* there is of course.)

> If so, how do you maintain this documentation afterwards?

NA. Nothing to maintain.

> Is it possible to generate Docs based on the description from Unit tests with some automatic tool?

Asking for 3rd party software/libraries is offtopic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

about automatic documentation, take a look on godoc - https://go.dev/blog/godoc

i don't know about specific usage of unit-test in golang (everyone using it - same as in other languages), but besides them bdd is also popular, for such a stuff take a look on godog - https://github.com/cucumber/godog

about `Asking for 3rd party software/libraries is offtopic on SO` - golang is all about 3rd party libraries :)

p.s. probably you can use pattern `godo(.{1})` to find any packages for go :)